# JavaScript recursive implementation of integer partition without reaarangement

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

**Problem**: Integer Partition without Rearrangement

**Input**: An arrangement S of nonnegative numbers {s1, . . . , sn} and an integer k. 
**Output**: The largest job from partitioning S into k or fewer ranges, to minimize the maximum sum over all the ranges, without reordering any of the numbers.

Example input = `[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]` should output the largest job which is only 1,700 because the array would optimally be partition as such `100 200 300 400 500 | 600 700 | 800 900`.

My function is not working. For the example it is outputting 2,400 when it should output 1,700. Can't figure out what's wrong.

## My Code

```
var integerPartitionRec = function(n, k, S) {
    function sum(p, c) {
        return p + c;
    }

    if (i === 1) return S[1];
    if (k === 1) return S.slice(0, n).reduce(sum);

    var cost, min_cost = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        cost = Math.max(integerPartitionRec(i, k - 1, S), S.slice(i).reduce(sum));
        min_cost = Math.min(min_cost, cost);
    }

    return min_cost;
};

var run = function() {

    var test = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900];

    console.log(integerPartitionRec(test.length, 3, test));
};

run();
```

Comment: Is there a question here or are you just sharing your code?

Comment: The codes not working. For the example input it should return 1,700 but returns 2,400

Comment: what is `i` in if (i === 1) return S[1]; ?

Comment: @RiaD I think it should be `n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your algorithm:

- If `n == 1` you have an array of size 1 which you can't split so the optimal solution is to not split and return the value of the element which is also the sum of the entire array: `S[0]` (you incorrectly put `S[1]`)
- If `k == 1` you cannot split anymore so return the sum of the entire array
- Otherwise, try to split at ever possible position (except at the very beginning `i=0` and at the very end `i=n`, because those are fake splits and if you can split it's always better to do so), check what's the result, and take the best split.

But in the recursive call you should consider only the array up to `n`, while in your code, in this line:

```
cost = Math.max(integerPartitionRec(i, k - 1, S), S.slice(i).reduce(sum));
```

You consider the entire array, because `S.slice(i).reduce(sum)` sums from i to the end of the array, even though from `n` to the end was already calculated in the "tail" of the previous call, so you consider it twice!

You can solve by telling slice to stop at `n`:

```
cost = Math.max(integerPartitionRec(i, k - 1, S), S.slice(i, n).reduce(sum));
```

Or you can avoid the use of `n` altogether by passing only the first part of the split to the recursive call:

```
var integerPartitionRec = function(k, S) {
    function sum(p, c) {
        return p + c;
    }

    if (k === 1 || S.length === 1) return S.reduce(sum);

    var cost, min_cost = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    for (var i = 1; i < S.length; i++) {
        cost = Math.max(integerPartitionRec(k - 1, S.slice(0, i)), S.slice(i).reduce(sum));
        min_cost = Math.min(min_cost, cost);
    }

    return min_cost;
};
```

Comment: I ended up changing it to `cost = Math.max(integerPartitionRec(i, k - 1, S, S.slice(i, n).reduce(sum));` but your answer showed me what was wrong. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's also a valid solution, edited my answer to explain what was wrong and show the possible solutions, let me know if it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

I did some random changes and it prints now 1700

```
var integerPartitionRec = function(n, k, S) {
    function sum(p, c) {
        return p + c;
    }

    if (n === 1) return S[1];
    if (k === 1) return S.slice(0, n).reduce(sum);

    var cost, min_cost = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        cost = Math.max(integerPartitionRec(i, k - 1, S), S.slice(i, n).reduce(sum));
        min_cost = Math.min(min_cost, cost);
    }

    return min_cost;
};

var run = function() {

    var test = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900];

    console.log(integerPartitionRec(test.length, 3, test));
};

run();
```

But I'd rather use another algorithm: you may use binary search on the answer and then check in `O(n)` whether it's possible to divide array to `k` parts where each is less than some constant. It'll be `O(n log sum)` instead of `O(n^2)`

Comment: You did some random changes?